# Which factors determine whether a set of variables are suitable for factor analysis?

Tags: statistics, factoring

**Which factors determine whether a set of variables are suitable for factor analysis?**

I am looking as much for an explanation of the question as a tentative answer to it. So grateful for any help on the subject.